# java CDI doesn't work correctly

Tags: jsf, cdi

When I'm pressing on button "send", I get empty screen instead of the name that I entered in index.xhtml. What could go wrong?

I have the following files:

Index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
   <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
      <h:form>
         <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}" />
         <h:commandButton value="send" action="act" />
      </h:form>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

act.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{userBean.name}"/>
</f:view>
</html>
```

UserBean.java:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public UserBean() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

beans.xml:

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: To exclude the obvious, what package did you import `@SessionScoped` from?

Comment: import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

Comment: As I guessed. See duplicate.